# Graph api (facebook) is too slow

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

While I'm using the Graph API to simple action, like this for example:

```
require 'src/facebook.php';

# facebook class
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXX',
  'secret' => 'XXX',
));

for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++)
{
    $url = $facebook->api('/Intel');
    echo $url['name'] . '<br />';
}
```

(just a quick example, I want to return 9 different pages but it doesn't matter now)

Well, this action took 9 - 10 SECONDS! too much.. and this is the only acion on the page (you can try run it and see).

What can I do? (if I'm using FQL via api [as method fql.query] it doesn't improve the running time, I checked it) I have to using graph api.

By the way, I'm using PHP SDK 3.0.1 (newest version.. maybe this is the problem?)

Comment: I get response times around 250 milliseconds. So it's not Facebook. Maybe your server has limited bandwidth.

Comment: Really? strange.. but the server works pretty fast for my other websites.

Comment: Can you send me the full code you tested? I try to running the same code on another server and again it took 9-10 seconds.

Comment: I tried on two another servers and again.. it took too much.. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you realize that you are making a remote call in a loop? It will make several remote calls one by one, thats why its slow. API is damn fast.
What I would suggest you is to use FQL here and send multiple queries in batch. This way you make one remote call and get data of several queries together.

```
/**
 * FQL multiquery
 */
$multiquery_fql[ 'query1' ] = $query1;
$multiquery_fql[ 'query2' ] = $query2;
$multiquery_fql = json_encode( $multiquery_fql );
$multiquery_result = $facebook->api(array(
    "method"    => "fql.multiquery",
    "queries"     => $multiquery_fql,
    'access_token' => '' // fill a generic token here (granted to app, independent of user)
));
```

And I would always recommend using an app. Its better to get your app blocked in case something goes wrong instead of IP.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working better then my code, but I still have a little problem of speed (I updated the code on test.php, can you tell me if its a normal speed?) and.. what you mean using app? I create an app but this page just for test which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: By the way, I see that sometimes the multiquery omits pages from the code. (you can see on the page test.php.. do refresh several times and see that sometimes details of pages are missing)

Comment: The test.php is almost instant for me. After resolving DNS, it loads within a sec.

Comment: How do you know that there is a DNS problem? I tried the code on two others hosting services (with another domain) and the speed is the same.

Comment: When did I say its a DNS problem? I said "for me", after resolving DNS which is also fast, the query just loads up fine within a sec.

Answer (score 1):

for this part of the graph api you dont need the api, so dont use it. just fetch `http://graph.facebook.com/Intel` via curl and json_decode it.

or if you can use it

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/Intel'));
```

Comment: cUrl can be a good idea - but.. why did the api was created if its too slow? your json code is working slowly for me and it doesn't work via the php sdk so maybe its really my server. thank you.

Comment: just call the url in the browser or via wget to see the speed. on my server its in the 50MS area.
(maybe you have a problem with DNS resolving, got this once, dns lookup duration 500-750MS, changed DNS to other server and it was down to 50-100MS)

Comment: I tried the same code on another two server, with other domain / DNA. can you send me the code you used? I edit the question with the full code, i don't think there is a problem with, but just tell me if its the same..